# How to force to install an "incompatible" TYPO3-Extension with composer?

Tags: composer-php, typo3

Lets say I use TYPO3 7.6 Composer installation. Now I run into following problem:

An Extension in the latest version defines in ext_emconf.php a required TYPO3-Version

```
'typo3' => '6.0.0-6.2.99',
```

I tested the Extension already in TYPO3 7 without any problems. In a none composer installation I could install the extension via extension manager and answer the warning with "I know what I'm doing" BUT with composer I can not install the Extension!

I mean yes I could

- wait for the developer to update...
- fork the extension and change the version in ext_emconf.php :-(

or  what?

Is there a way to force composer to install this "incompatible" Extension somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possbile to force an install by composer if the requirements are not met. But there are still a few tricks. You can require TYPO3 7LTS and tell composer to threat it as 6.2. But this of course means that other extensions might now be incompatible. This can be acieved in your `composer.json` by

```
"require": {
   "typo3/cms": "^7.6 as 6.2.31"
}
```

If the extension has a development branch that is already combatible and only the release is missing you can require the branch instead of a release. If the extension is registered on packagist.org that would be

```
"require": {
   "vendor/extension": "dev-<branchname>"
}
```

If it is not registered on packagist but has a `composer.json` file you can add the repository of the extension to your root `composer.json` to make the branch requireable.

```
"repositories": [
    {"type": "git", "url": "https://github.com/vendor/extension.git"}
]
```

But the best way is of course to make the extension compatible and if it already is, to ask for an official release that supports TYPO3 7LTS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I use composer in my virtual test-environments. This behaviour makes it a bit hard to just test some extensions. Why can't composer ignore the emconf if I specify a version in composer file that I require? Well I think its by design. Not for my 100% satisfaction but the answer is given. Thanks! resolved.